# Polling an object's public variable

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I would like to notify a program immediately when there is a change in a bool variable that is a public variable of an object. For example;

say, an instance of class `conn` is created within a windows form application.

there is a `Ready` variable, a public variable of the class conn is present.

I would like to get notified whenever there is a change in this variable.

I did a quick research to solve this problem within stackoverflow but the answers suggested the use of property, which, I think is not suitable for my application.

Comment: You need to clarify this I'm afraid. Why would a property "not be suitable"? `INotifyPropertyChanged` would be a good place to start.

Comment: There's nothing built into the language, you'll have to manually implement it using custom events.

Comment: I doubt you will be able to convince most .Net developers that properties are "not suitable" for a particular application, without supplying any code to demonstrate their unsuitability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume you are referring to a field when you say public variable.

With few exceptions, it is preferable to not have public fields in C# classes, but rather private fields with public accessors:

```
class BadClass
{
    public int Value; // <- NOT preferred
}

class GoodClass
{
    private int value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set { this.value = value; }
    }
}
```

One of the reasons to structure your code this way is so you can do more than one thing in the property's getter and setters.  An example that applies to your scenario is property change notification:

```
class GoodClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name);
        }
    }
}
```

If you were to implement your class like this, you could use it this way:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    var instance = new GoodClass();
    instance.PropertyChanged += this.OnPropertyChanged;
}

void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Value")
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

If you change the `Value` property, not only will it change the value of the underlying field, but it will also raise the [`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event, and call your event handler.

Comment: Depending on your requirements it might be benificial to add some checking like `if (this.value != value) { ... }` to your property setter to avoid raising the `PropertyChanged` event when nothing changed.

Comment: @WillemDuncan That's a great suggestion.

Comment: Thank you for this great response and for your time. This is what I need in a form that I can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for this. The most straight forward way to do this in .NET is the event system. In the class `conn`, create an event:

```
public event EventHandler ReadyChanged;
```

and then when you create an instance of `conn`, subscribe to that event:

```
o.ReadyChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    // do something
}
```

and then finally, when the flag changes in `conn`, fire the event via a new method named `OnReadyChanged`:

```
protected virtual void OnReadyChanged()
{
    if (ReadyChanged != null) { ReadyChanged(this, new EventArgs()); }
}
```